# Projection onto a plane that doesn't pass through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have 3 normalized vectors $a, b, c \in \Bbb R^3 $, That define a plane $\{\ t\ a+s\ b+c\ :\ t, s \in \Bbb R\ \}$.
I would like to project a point $v = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ onto the plane.
If the plane passed through the origin (if $c$ was $0_{\Bbb R^3}$) that would be simple.
But when $\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|=1$, how do you find $v$'s projection onto the plane?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You could translate the space so the plane passes through the origin and then translate back?

Comment: I didn't manage to do it

Comment: That is not a plane. You probably forgot $=0$ or something

Comment: @mathreadler $a,b,c$ are vectors

Comment: Oh, right. Could be good to indicate it on the symbols somehow so that people don't mistake them for scalars. Like $\bf a$ or $\vec a$

Comment: @NitsanBenHanoch What do you mean? Subtract $c$ from every vector you have (giving you new coordinates) and the add $c$ back afterwards. In other words, project $v-c$ onto $\{t\ a+s\ b\ :\ t, s \in \Bbb R\}$ and then add $c$ onto the projected vector (I quite sure that's the method if I haven't messed it up in my head)

Comment: @Shuri2060 I finally got you. I ended up using your method, because it gives the answer in terms of $B=(a, b, a×b)$'s coordinates-vector, which is more useful in my case (computed little 3d library)... so thanks^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w$ be the vector from the *point* $c$ to the point $v$, and let $n$ be the normal vector to the plane (so $n = a \times b$.)  Let $u$ be the projection of $w$ onto $n$.  Then you have a right triangle with $w$ as the hypotenuse and $u$ as one of the legs.   The other leg $w-u$ is the vector from $c$ to the point you want.  So the answer is the *point* $c+w-u$.

Comment: Thanks, with a pencil and a paper it seems great:)